# Why does my noteook drains energy during hibernation on win 10?

Tags: windows-10, hibernate, lenovo-laptop

I found out that my laptop Lenovo Y50-70 misbehaved when in hibernation. When it goes to hibernation with unplugged power cable, or when I unplug it in hibernation, the HDD probably starts to load or what, which drains the energy. It starts to make sounds like when the laptop is on, however after some seconds it dies. After appr. 5s that again. And again and again, until the battery is totally drained. It stops, when the cable is back in.

The laptop is really in hibernation and I know, that means it copies memory data to hibe-file, so why it does this?? Could there be any problem in BIOS?

When it is powered off normally, it doesn't do that.

I'd add, this computer had win8 originally, but I upgraded it to win10...

UPDATE: I already have the newest version of BIOS for this NB. I'm of course entering hibernation, not sleep mode or anything else, I'm not stupid. And surely have version with 1TB HDD. Still doing it, and only in hibernation - not in sleep mode (this surely confuses me), not after regular shutdown. Any idea??

Comment: I think you're confusing hibernation with suspension and are using the latter.

Comment: Get the newest version of the Lenovo System Update application from the Lenovo support site, download it and install it. Then see if there are any drivers (especially BIOS) to update.

Comment: While it is making noises, does it look to be sleeping? It also seems that the Lenovo Y50-70 has an SSD (which doesn't make noises) rather than an HDD.

Comment: I am for sure using hibernation and this version of NB has 1TB HDD. 
OK, I'll check BIOS drivers, however, I think they're newest. However, I'll definately try to reinstall them...

Comment: For your/more info, when the NTB is in sleep mode, this doesn't occur.